# Get error using r.reclass in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, reclassify

I am trying to use r.reclass function on a Land Cover raster in QGIS 3.4.
The operation is quite basic stuff and the settings are attached below.

[image: r.reclass settings]

However, I get an error that prevents the creation of my output raster.
The error should be "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]", as printed below.

[image]

I am running QGIS 3.4 on a MacBook. I do not get any error when performing the same operation on QGIS 3.2 on Windows.

I attach the screenshot of the Log Messages pane for more information.

[image]